# How to update my JPanel in a simple multithread condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jpanel

There are 3 threads , every thread will add a JButton to JPanel , and the final 3 window should have 3 Jbuttons respectively , but 1 jbutton and 2,3 respectively , i try to use wait() and notifyAll() method to update JPanel to 3 Jbuttons , but failed

(BTW,i am new to this , the problem originated from a complex Server_Client contact list matter ,i simplify it a lot  like below codes)

[JFrame example shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a585.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;

class TestPanel implements Runnable {
//    the common Jpanel of 3 thread
static JPanel SharedPanel = new JPanel();

//    the common JFrame of 3 thread
static JFrame SharedFrame = new JFrame();


//    the JFrame window x,y position
static int Position = 200;

JButton Button1;
String ButtonName;


public TestPanel(String name) {

//        pass a name to JButton
    this.ButtonName = name;


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

//      initializing a "A" named JButton to the common Jpanel
    new Thread(new TestPanel("A")).start();


//      initializing a "B" named JButton to the common Jpanel

    new Thread(new TestPanel("B")).start();

//      initializing a "C" named JButton to the common Jpanel

    new Thread(new TestPanel("C")).start();

}


@Override
public void run() {
//      initializing jbutton 
    Button1 = new JButton(ButtonName);

//        add Jbutton to the static common jpanel
    SharedPanel.add(Button1);

//create a new JFrame ,cause 3 window need 3 different jframe (with the same content)
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

 //      add that common shared japnel the Jframe
    jf.add(SharedPanel);

//        default initializing of window
    jf.setSize(500, 500);

//        to prevent overlap window , offset a little bit for better observation
    jf.setLocation(Position += 50, Position += 50);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);


}


}
```

How to refresh each window after a new Jbutton was add to jpanel?

(i also try to assign a while function in the end of Run(),but i discover it is useless, maybe my question is easy for you , thanks for your good help !)

Comment: 1). Please read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and about [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). This will probably help you to create your application. 
2). You cannot share a `JPanel` between multiple frames, so you need to create and fill your panel three times (for example you can build a method that creates and fills the panel). Probably in your code it would be enought to remove the modifier `static` from `SharedPanel`.

Comment: 3). Please use Java Naming Convension. This means `CapitalizedClassName`, `firstCharacterSmallVariableName` and `firstCharacterSmallMethodName`. So not `SharedPanel` but `sharedPanel`. `Button1` -> `button1` and so on.

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy , it sounds like feasible , i try later ,but i would appreciate it if you can show me a demo with a simple skeleton

Answer (score 1):

calling:

```
revalidate();
```

and then

```
repaint();
```

on your shared JPanel will refresh it.

If you wish to refresh all frames you can call those methods on the frames with "notifyAll".

Comment: Could you please code a detailed example ?i certainly know notifyAll() and revalidate() , however i failed in that trial.

Comment: @Super-ilad I just chekced and the issue is that when you add a give a Component another parent (JPanel is the child of a JFrame in your program) it will remove it from other frames.
There could be another solution by creating a custom JPanel class that includes notifiying all created entities to add the same component added to it (in your case, the buttons) and repaint them. would that help?

Comment: @Eretz KdoshaYes, it sounds like feasible , i try later ,but i would appreciate it if you can show me a demo with a simple skeleton